# Error in creating a database dump on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When trying to make a postgreSQL database dump we got the following error and the process stops immediately.

Command used:

```
openbravo@master.akluck.com:~

07/26 11:48:11> pg_dump -U tad -h localhost -p 5932 -F c -b -v -f /home/openbravo/dump26072018.dmp openbravo
```

Output:

```
pg_dump: reading schemas

pg_dump: reading user-defined tables

pg_dump: schema with OID 67046 does not exist

pg_dump: *** aborted because of error
```

Can anyone guide me how to sort this issue?

Update:

I followed this tutorial

http://www.aukema.org/2011/06/fixing-complex-corruption-in-my-dna.html

And I can see there are objects without a schemaname in the pg_tables.

[image]

But I don't know how to update those missing schemanames in the pg_tables. The last part of the tutorial is not quite explanatory. Hope someone can throw some light.

Comment: Welcome on the DBA SE! Note, screenshots don't look very well, if you can use text copy-paste, use that.

Comment: @peterh What do you mean by "don't look very well"?